# Include Image with uncertain end of filename / range

Tags: includegraphics, business-cards

I would like to include an image using includegraphics.
This is for a series of business cards and I have to rely on an external source for generating these images. I will include these image names from a csv. The Generator will give me filenames that follow the syntax [UniqueName]_[UniqueNumber].jpg
Problem is, I will only know [UniqueName]. The Number will be random. Is there a command that allows to include the image regardless of it's ending? Something like

```
\includegraphics[height=17mm,width=17mm]{[UniqueName]_*.jpg}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can specify the beginning using \graphicspath{...}. You will still need some mechanism for handling the rest of the pathname.

Comment: @MS-SPO Why does it matter if these images are business cards or not? The tag does not seem useful for this question.

Comment: As it's stated "(...) This is for a series of business cards (...)" using graphics is one way to create or process BCs. But yes, if you limit it to typography or layout, perhaps not.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\includegraphics[width=17mm]{\FILENAME}
```

(are you sure you want to specify width and height, that will distort the image.) and then do something like

```
pdflatex '\def\FILENAME{'`ls *_.jpg`'}\input{yourfile.tex}'
```

where the details of the quoting depend on what shell/commandline you use. The above works in bash assuming only one file is listed by `ls *_.jpg`

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to use this. Do you mean bash command as the shell in Windows? 
I am writing my Tex code on Overleaf so that would not be an option.
I am generating a series of cards using this system as a rough template, so filenames (at least half of them, as I said) will be included in the csv and the qr code will be associated to the other data of the card owner.

https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/mailmerged-business-cards/gnnhcjvkvcfd

Comment: Image size will always be the same as it is a square qr code, but thanks for the heads up. Before you mention it: I am bound to a company tool that doesn't allow me to generate the QRs myself. I have been there.

Comment: Also: your code *looks* like (not an expert here) it will allow any beginning, not any end. Wich would be the opposite of what I need. Do I see that correctly?

Workaround, if this does not work as easily as I thought, will be to batch rename all files and remove the number. I would like to avoid that.